# Getting a Public Function to Copy Down Column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I made the below Public Function to choose a quarter based on the month number in my data.

```
Public Function quarter()

Dim Number As Integer

Dim quarterChosen As String

Number = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value

Select Case Number

Case 1 To 3

quarterChosen = "Q1"

Case 4 To 6

quarterChosen = "Q2"

Case 7 To 9

quarterChosen = "Q3"

Case 10 To 12

quarterChosen = "Q4"

End Select

quarter = quarterChosen


End Function
```

It works but when I drag it down to copy it down it stills considers the active cell the original cell started at. I need to rewrite the formula to get the result I want. How do I get that active cell to change as I drag or copy it down?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use Application.Volatile in the upper part of your function. I've just wrote this one for you and all works my end :)

```
    Public Function Quarter(arg1 As Long)
    Dim quarterChosen As String

    Application.Volatile

    Select Case arg1
        Case 1 To 3
        quarterChosen = "Q1"

        Case 4 To 6
        quarterChosen = "Q2"

        Case 7 To 9
        quarterChosen = "Q3"

        Case 10 To 12
        quarterChosen = "Q4"
    End Select

    Quarter = quarterChosen
    End Function
```

You should also pass the function the cell you want to evaluate.

Comment: Got it, that's much better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pass your input cell as an argument of your function (and add an output type), along the line of this.

So you enter the formula in B1 `=quarter(A1)`.

```
Public Function quarter(r As Range) As String

Dim quarterChosen As String

Select Case r.Value
    Case 1 To 3:   quarter = "Q1"
    Case 4 To 6:   quarter = "Q2"
    Case 7 To 9:   quarter = "Q3"
    Case 10 To 12: quarter = "Q4"
    Case Else:     quarter = "n/a"
End Select

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Better to return an actual error, rather than "n/a" as a string.  `... = CVErr(xlErrNA)` ( declare function `As Variant`)